# Openelec(Kodi) Amazon Instant video?

Tags: raspbmc, kodi, openelec, shairplay

As far as I know(I researched!) Kodi can only support Amazon Prime Instant video, right? Well, I don't have a prime account, and am not planning on getting one(I live in Muscat, Oman, where a prime account would be practically useless). Is it possible to run any program at all to get Amazon Instant Video to play? I have tried all of the addons I have found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible at the moment to run Amazon Prime on the Raspberry Pi.
Perhaps when the new Kernel 4.4 is released it might work eventually again. But at the moment no chance :(

Comment: When will kernel 4.4 be released? Do you know?

Comment: No idea, I'm sorry :(

Comment: What kernel is it right now?