# Amazon Instant Video on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, linux, archlinux

I know, I know, there are tons of articles out there about Amazon PRIME instant video, and how it works on Kodi. However, I don't have a prime account, and am not planning on getting one.

I have researched far and wide, deep and shallow, to find this: 
If you want to play Amazon instant video without a prime account, you have to pay.

Options:

1. VNC client for RPi: for power points and that stuff, it updates the display at far to slow a rate for video playback.
2. rplay: it should work, but doesn't for me, because I didn't pay for the license code, so I can't mirror my iPad.
3. Playon: works great! Problem: you have to pay for it.
4. Plex Media Center: no option, it doesn't support DRM protected videos
5. Adobe Flash Player or Silverlight in browser plugin: I have an RPi B+, so no support.
6. Other Linux OS: I tried Arch Linux and Ubuntu, but found out that Ubuntu was for the RPi 2, and Arch Linux wasn't fully compatible.
7. Picast: not able to play DRM files

Help! I am willing to try ANYTHING. LITERALLY ANYTHING to get Amazon Instant Video to work on the RPi b+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openelec(Kodi) Amazon Instant video?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39302/openeleckodi-amazon-instant-video)

Comment: So, it sounds like you're asking for a way to get a paid service for free, aka pirating? That would be off-topic here and is decidedly unethical.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he means. I think we're just looking for a way to watch Amazon Instant videos, accessed with a standard Amazon account, as opposed to Amazon Prime videos, accessed with an upgraded Amazon Prime account. The sections where payment is mentioned refer to paying for the client software used to watch the paid-for streams, not the streams themselves.

Comment: No, what I mean is that maybe, if possible, is would like to send streams from my Mac laptop to my rpi via like USB or Ethernet cable or something. Maybe a .strm file?

Comment: I think I might have found a way......

Comment: Miracast might be a solution. I have an android tablet, so that might, just might work with OSMC or something. Give me a few more days.